# How to delete objects with common values from an array in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Having an array of objects like this one

```
   "medios":[  
      {  
         "Key":"1",
         "Text":"Cheque"
      },
      {  
         "Key":"2",
         "Text":"Tarjeta de Crédito"
      },
      {  
         "Key":"3",
         "Text":"Tarjeta de Crédito"
      },
      {  
         "Key":"4",
         "Text":"Tarjeta de Crédito"
      },
      {  
         "Key":"5",
         "Text":"Transferencia Bancaria"
      }
   ]
```

I need to be able to delete objects that has the same "Text" value (Tarjeta de Crédito, for example), until I only keep one of them. Any idea of how to achieve that?

I tried by using a loop over the array, but don't know how to delete the specific objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and dont add element when already present.

```js
var medios = [{"Key": "1","Text": "Cheque"},{"Key": "2","Text": "Tarjeta de Crédito"},{"Key": "3","Text": "Tarjeta de Crédito"},{"Key": "4","Text": "Tarjeta de Crédito"},{"Key": "5","Text": "Transferencia Bancaria"}];

medios = medios.reduce((c, n) =>
  c.find(el => el.Text == n.Text) ? c : [...c, n], []);
console.log(medios);
```

Comment: This solution is not efficient. It has a time complexity of *O(n²)*  while it can be done in *O(n)*.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Map` to key your data by `Text` so that you will only get unique entries. And then get the values from that map to rebuild your array again:

```js
const obj = {"medios":[{ "Key":"1","Text":"Cheque"},{ "Key":"2","Text":"Tarjeta de Crédito"},{ "Key":"3","Text":"Tarjeta de Crédito"},{ "Key":"4","Text":"Tarjeta de Crédito"},{  "Key":"5","Text":"Transferencia Bancaria"}]};

obj.medios = Array.from(new Map(obj.medios.map(m => [m.Text, m])).values());

console.log(obj.medios);
```

Comment: You are removing previous occurrencies as is, while removing dupes implies to keep the first key in which value is present

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini, the OP did not specify that the first should be kept. Reading the question, there is no reason to believe the first is more important than the last. The question was only to delete objects that have the same Text, which this code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.filter()` array method combined with a seperate array to track which texts we already have to create a new array containing only the wanted elements. The first entry will remain, so we expect key 2 to remain and key 3 and key 4 to be removed in the new array.

```js
const data = {
  "medios":[  
    {  
     "Key":"1",
     "Text":"Cheque"
    },
    {  
     "Key":"2",
     "Text":"Tarjeta de Crédito"
    },
    {  
     "Key":"3",
     "Text":"Tarjeta de Crédito"
    },
    {  
     "Key":"4",
     "Text":"Tarjeta de Crédito"
    },
    {  
     "Key":"5",
     "Text":"Transferencia Bancaria"
    }
   ]
};

const seen = [];

const result = {
  "medios": data.medios.filter( entry => {
    const already_seen = seen.includes( entry.Text );
    if ( already_seen ) return false;
    else {
      seen.push( entry.Text );
      return true;
    }
  })
};

console.log( result );
```

Answer (score 1):

The most clean way to manage this IMHO is through simple lodash _.uniqBy() method:

```js
const medios = [  
      {  
         "Key":"1",
         "Text":"Cheque"
      },
      {  
         "Key":"2",
         "Text":"Tarjeta de Crédito"
      },
      {  
         "Key":"3",
         "Text":"Tarjeta de Crédito"
      },
      {  
         "Key":"4",
         "Text":"Tarjeta de Crédito"
      },
      {  
         "Key":"5",
         "Text":"Transferencia Bancaria"
      }
   ]


console.log(_.uniqBy(medios, 'Text'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How come the cleanest way is to add a library ?

Comment: Clean coding involves semantic, _.unicBy() is a method from a 36k++ stars library and does exactly what states with a readable interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [_.uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#uniqBy) from lodash to keep it simple and clean in the following way

```
// medios = [{Key: 1, Text: '' }, {Key: 2, Text: '' } ]
medios = _.uniqBy(medios, 'Text');
```

Comment: Although some complies that lodash is an additional library, it makes code really more readable and this is a primary feature of modern coding. All other examples in the page will require comment to be understood < 10s

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini you are right

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` . Inside reduce callback use `find` to check if the accumulator array contains an object with this text. `find` returns a Boolean value. If false then push the current object inside the accumulator

```js
let medios = [{
    "Key": "1",
    "Text": "Cheque"
  },
  {
    "Key": "2",
    "Text": "Tarjeta de Crédito"
  },
  {
    "Key": "3",
    "Text": "Tarjeta de Crédito"
  },
  {
    "Key": "4",
    "Text": "Tarjeta de Crédito"
  },
  {
    "Key": "5",
    "Text": "Transferencia Bancaria"
  }
]
let k = medios.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let findText = acc.find((item) => {
    return item.Text.toLowerCase() === curr.Text.toLowerCase();
  });
  if (!findText) {
    acc.push(curr)
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(k)
```